# Add auto_increment value to table with existing data

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with around 400 rows in it on phpmyadmin. I have added an id column and it is the primary key and is an auto increment. How can I update the table with sql and add a value for each row in the id column without ?
I was trying to do it with something like

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cong WHERE 'ID' IS NULL) > 0
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 1
    UPDATE cong SET 'ID' = MAX('ID')+1
END
```

but that comes back with an error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cong WHERE 'ID' IS NULL) > 0 BEGIN SET ROWCOUN' at line 1
```

How can I achieve adding the auto increment number into each row?

Comment: One way (maybe not the best way), You could take your existing data (main table), backup the data to a backup table, then delete all from your main table. Reinsert the backedup data into the main table, and let the auto increment field populate as the records are inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you originally did not have the id column, inserted the ~400 rows, and then decided you needed an id and added the column, setting it as a primary key and auto_increment. Now you want to go back and add values to each of the ~400 rows which did not previously have an ID.

When you added the primary key and auto_increment, it should have created those auto_increment values for you. I just did a test with several rows of data (a single varchar column), then through phpMyAdmin (since you tagged your post with phpmyadmin) I added a new column id of type INT, checking the A_I (auto_increment) checkbox and selecting PRIMARY as the key. Browsing the data shows that my existing rows each have an ID.

Are you saying your column is a primary key with auto_increment set and the field is blank? It doesn't make sense that MySQL would allow that. If that's true, can you post your table structure?

Comment: I removed the column ID and re-added it and each row does have an id. I must have set the id as a varchar by mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I'm delighted that you were able to resolve it.